# Adding 365days or Year in SQL Query - MOODLE

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I am trying to create a report where we can see course completion date and the date when it will expire. Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT u.firstname AS 'Firstname' , u.lastname AS 'Lastname', cat.name AS 'Organisation', c.fullname AS 'course',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%Y-%m-%d') AS completed

FROM prefix_course_completions AS p

JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cat 
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON p.course = c.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON p.userid = u.id
WHERE c.enablecompletion = 1
ORDER BY u.firstname
```

I'm trying to add a new column where 'completed' columns data + 365 = expiration date. I have tried so many methods like DATE_ADD/DATEADD but I still can't get it. Can you please help me. I would appreciate any suggestions and help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),
                     INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d'
           ) AS expiration_date
```

If you want exactly 365 days (so things are off around leap years), you can use `INTERVAL 365 DAY` instead.

Comment: wow sir thanks for your fast reply. I have tried the code above but I am getting a **Query failed** message: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d' at line 3_ 

I inserted the code below the completed and also tried to use DATEADD instead of DATE_ADD but still no luck.

Comment: @Nightshade I suspect you left out the comma before `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: so dumb of me. I forgot the comma. Been taking care of my kid in hospital for the last 3 days. Thank you so much sir's for the help. Everything works fine now. Thank you! @Barmar

Comment: Thank you @gordon Linoff